# Exclude components from ng-bootstrap module in Angular 2

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I want to import some specific components from ng-bootstrap module in Angular 2.
Can I do that?

I have custom tabset created from existing ng-bootstrap component.
After importing ng-bootstrap I have getting module duplication error.

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 3):

It is easy: just import individual modules from [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io) instead of importing the whole `NgbModule`. For example to only import alert-related functionality you would do:

```
import { NgbAlertModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/alert/alert.module';

...

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, NgbAlertModule.forRoot()], 
  declarations: [App]
  bootstrap: [App]
}) 
export class AppModule {}
```

Of course you would have to import and list all the modules that you are using but the advantage here is that you can precisely reference only things that are used in your application.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore with ng-bootstrap 3+ - use the other answer

Answer (score 1):

Two common mistakes done by people who are using ng-bootstrap for the first time:

1. Include both `NgbModule` and individual components and get that duplication error.
2. Miss "Module" suffix while importing most of components
   (e.g.  `import { NgbTabset } from ...` instead of  `import { NgbTabsetModule } from ...`)

So as the answer to your question just remove the `NgbModule` if you've imported that and import `NgbTabsetModule` instead.

Just like this:

```
// Remove this line -> import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NgbTabsetModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
//...
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...
    NgbTabsetModule,
  ],
  declarations: [YourComponent]
})
export class YourComponent {}
```

P.S. Also there is no need to provide full path while importing the component as is mentioned in other answer(s). Importing from `'@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'` works fine.