# Is ng-bootstrap importing all the components

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap

I'm new in [ng-boostrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) and followed their  [getting started](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) guide. Here's the important part of the code.

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
 ...

@NgModule({
  
  imports:      [ 
   NgbModule.forRoot(),
    ...
   ],
```

Is ng-bootstrap importing all the components like ngb-carousel, ngb-progressbar and etc even though I'm not using it?

There's another bootstrap library, [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/) that does importing each of the components like this

```
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
@NgModule({
  imports: [ModalModule.forRoot(),
   ...]
})
export class AppModule(){}
```

which is also how you import components modules similar in [angular material](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it imports all components. You can see [it here](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/index.ts#L84):

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NgbAlertModule.forRoot(), NgbButtonsModule.forRoot(), ...
  ],
  exports: NGB_MODULES
})
export class NgbRootModule {
}

@NgModule({imports: NGB_MODULES, exports: NGB_MODULES})
export class NgbModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders { return {ngModule: NgbRootModule}; }
}
```

It's probably done for convenience. Since individual modules are exported as well:

```
export {
  NgbAccordionModule,
  NgbPanelChangeEvent,
  ...
```

You can import directly only the modules you're interested in.

Comment: @brijmcq, no, I guess over time the building tools will be able to tree shake these unused modules. Also you can import directly only the modules you're interested in. I've updated y answer

Comment: i was able to found how to import individual modules in another resources. ng-bootstrap should update their documentation :)

Comment: @brijmcq, it's the same way as any other module. you read this in-depth article about modules [Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f)

Comment: I just thought there might be something interesting why they would indicate in their getting started guide to import all the components

Comment: i'll definitely check that article! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: i think this is a duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42527676/exclude-components-from-ng-bootstrap-module-in-angular-2  should probably delete my question.

Comment: @brijmcq, you can't delete questions with answers

Comment: `ng-bootstrap` didn't work for me. Each thing I tried, and then ran the web-pack analyzer, `ng-bootstrap` would import all of their components ~530kb. The `forRoot()` does not work anymore. I was able to import single component with `ngx-bootstrap` library instead.